# Using <button> instead of <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using ReactJS along with a Bootstrap Nav Bar. Bootstrap uses an `<a>` tag for the navigation buttons. I want the buttons to be able to scroll down to a different component on the page without using an href. I have a scrollFunction to scroll to a section depending on what was pressed. If I use the `<a>` tag and change it to a button type, the format is totally different and I lose the "active" page style along with the pointer when I hover over the button.

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

If I change the Education `<a>` tag to:

```
<button class="nav-link" type="button" onClick={()=>scrollFunc("education")} style={{background:"transparent", border:"none"}}>Education</button>
```

Then I will get this output.

[image]

Finally, if I change the Education to:

```
<a class="nav-link" type="button" onClick={()=>scrollFunc("education")} style={{background:"transparent", border:"none"}}>Education <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

I will get this output:

[image]

I would like to get the output of the first picture, without the href. Also when I hover over I want the mouse icon to be a pointer like shown here:

[image]

Please help me do this, I am relatively new to Web Development.

Comment: For the mouse part, try adding "cursor: pointer" to the css. (To add to the html, do style="cursor: pointer")

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mega12345mega for the answer:

```
<a class="nav-link" onClick={()=>scrollFunc("education")} style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Education <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```